# Should I add @Component annotation to all classes in Java Spring program?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Currently I use `@Component` only on my `Views`, `Controllers` and `Models`.
To be accurate, I use `@RestController` for `Views`, `@Service` for `Controllers` and `@Component` for `Models` (because I want to use Hibernate as an ORM provider)

My problem is that I also use `@Autowired` constructors which means that I can use only `@Component` based Objects in my constructor.
Sometimes I need to create a Controller that takes none-Component class. As an example - to add Config clas besides other `@Component` objects to my constructor .

What should I do in general:

1) Add `@Component` annotation to all Java classes.

2) Add `@Component` only to those classes that I need ? (which means that some my Config classes will have `@Component` when others Config classes will not.)

3) Not use `@Autowired` in situations like this, create a Controller in a regular way ?

4) Not use `@Autowired` constructors at all ?

5) Other ideas ?

Comment: Have you used `@Configuration` clases to create and wire controllers than don't have `@Component`? Non-component classes can be declared as @Bean then injected.

Comment: No,  I didn't use @ Configuration annotation.
Is it fine to add  @ Bean to all my classed or only to those that I need  ?

Comment: By create a Controller class do you mean to use `new` operator to create a Controller object ? If you are using `new` , then you are not using the spring framework properly.

Comment: @R.G , I didn't realise that it is so serious. 
Yes, I was planing to use "new".

So should I avoid "new" usage only when I create Models/Views/Controllers or in all project in general ?

Comment: @АлександрСергеевичДжус , this [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-basics) is a good place to start . When `new` is used , the object is not controlled by the framework and to get the full potential of spring framework , the lifecycle of the beans/objects are to be managed by the spring container. Please go through the document shared